# ACF of AR(p) models

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive, arma

Is there any other method to compute the sample autocorrelation function (ACF) of AR(p), the p$^{th}$ [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) except the Yule-Walker equations?

I want to determine if ACF is 0 except at lags 1,5,6,7 for the model:

$X_t$ =$Z_t$+ $\phi_1$$X_{t-1}$+ $\phi_5$$X_{t-5}$ + $\phi_6$$X_{t-6}$ + $\phi_7$$X_{t-7}$

And if the ACF is 0 except at lags 1,5,6,7 for this:

$X_t$ =$Z_t$+ $\phi_1$$X_{t-1}$+ $\phi_5$$X_{t-5}$ + $\phi_6$$X_{t-6}$